# Convert Powershell function to parallel process

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, workflow

The following code works perfectly sequentially but I would like to make it run in parallel.  I have quite a few other functions I want to convert as well and want this one to be the template for all the conversions I plan to make.  I don't know which would be best to use though.  Workflow or run-space.  I have had no success using either.

```
Function New-TestCimSession {
  [CmdletBinding(
    SupportsShouldProcess = $true
  )]
  param(
    [Parameter(
      Position = 0,
      Mandatory = $false,
      ValueFromPipeline = $true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
      HelpMessage = "Computer(s) you want to create a CimSession to")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string[]]
    $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,

    [Parameter(
      Position = 1,
      Mandatory = $false,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $True,
      HelpMessage = "Describe what the value of the parameter should be")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    $Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty
  )

  begin {
    Write-Verbose "New-TestCimSession: Started"
    Set-StrictMode -Version 1.0 #Option Explicit
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    $AllComputerObjects = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

    $SessionParams = @{
      ErrorAction = 'Stop'
    }
    $Opt = New-CimSessionOption -Protocol DCOM
    $SessionParams.SessionOption = $Opt

    if ($PSBoundParameters['Credential']) {
      $SessionParams.Credential = $Credential
    }
    else {
      $SessionParams.Credential = Get-Credential
    }
  }

  process {
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
      $SessionParams.ComputerName = $Computer
      $SessionParams.SessionOption = $Opt

      $NewComputerObject = [PSObject] @{}
      $NewComputerObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ComputerName' -Value "$Computer"

      try {
        $NewComputerObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'CimSession' -Value (New-CimSession @SessionParams)
      }
      catch {}

      if ($null -ne $NewComputerObject.CimSession) {
        $NewComputerObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'CimSessionConnected' -Value $true
      }
      else {
        $NewComputerObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'CimSessionConnected' -Value $false
      }
      $AllComputerObjects += $NewComputerObject
    }
  }

  end {
    Write-Verbose "New-TestCimSession: Completed"
    return , $AllComputerObjects
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say you did not have success with Workflows and Runspaces? Do you have a code? Obviously, running your function in a runspace or workflow is not going to help when the actual time consuming process is inside your function. I assume you are looking to 'parallel process' the code block inside your foreach loop. Then that's what you should put in a Runspace or Workflow or Jobs(Yeah, that's another way) and not the function.

Comment: You ask which to parallelization tool to use? If you just want to run a foreach loop in parallel (you can probably imagine what that looks like), check out the `-Parallel` argument: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1 If you want a more versatile but quick and dirty approach, consider Powershell jobs. If you want more control and better performance, try runspaces. If you want a simplier path to runspaces, try PoshRS https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob

Answer (score 0):

There are a few answers to this, but the one I know best is to use a `Powershell Job`. Here's an example on how you can use them:

```
$asyncBlock = {
  # Code to run asynchronously goes here
}

# Start the background job
$bgJob = Start-Job $asyncBlock

# Do other stuff here

# Wait for the background job to complete before continuing
$bgJob | Wait-Job

# Get the resulting output from the background job
$result = Receive-Job -Job $bgJob
```

If you want to run `New-TestCimSession` asynchronously in its entirely, just call it like so:

```
$bgJob = Start-Job { New-TestCimSession -Arguments go -Here }
$bgJob | Wait-Job
$result = $bgJob | Receive-Job
```

And then process `$result` as the output of that function.